# Finding similar corners in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I need to find similar corners in image (for example: 4 corners of a rectangle, same corners, just different orientation?).

[image]

I have this code:

```
    % read the image into MATLAB and convert it to grayscale
    I = imread('s2.jpg');
    Igray = rgb2gray(I);
    figure, imshow(I);
    % We can see that the image is noisy. We will clean it up with a few
    % morphological operations
    Ibw = im2bw(Igray,graythresh(Igray)); 
    se = strel('line',3,90);
    cleanI = imdilate(~Ibw,se);
    figure, imshow(cleanI);
    % Perform a Hough Transform on the image 
    % The Hough Transform identifies lines in an image 
   [H,theta,rho] = hough(cleanI);
   peaks  = houghpeaks(H,10); 
   lines = houghlines(Ibw,theta,rho,peaks);
   figure, imshow(cleanI)
   % Highlight (by changing color) the lines found by MATLAB
   hold on
```

After running this code I convert my starting image into a binary image with:

```
binary = im2bw(I);
```

after this I get a product from those 2 binary images and I think I get corners..

```
product = binary .* cleanI;
```

now I `imfuse` this picture with grayscale starting picture and get this:

[image]

I dont know what to do to get only those 4 corners!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you can post an image (or link to an image, that we can edit in, cause you can't add images yet), so we can more easily understand what you are trying to do. Also, add the code for the corner detection, so people see what you've tried.

Comment: [link](http://www.soil-net.com/album/Equipment/slides/Mobile%20Phone.jpg)
This picture for example, i want to find corners of the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok second try. Below a code that does not finally do the job but it might help.
Edge identifies the contours and with regionprops you get the characteristica of each identified element. As soon as you know what characteristics your desired object has you can filter it and plot it. I went through the Areas in shapedata.Area and the 6th largest was the one you were searching for. If you combine Area with some of the other charateristica you might get the one you want. As I said not ideal and final but perhaps a start ...

```
clear all
close all

source = imread('Mobile Phone.jpg');
im     = rgb2gray(source);
bw  = edge(im ,'canny',[],sqrt(2));
shapedata=regionprops (bwlabel(bw,8),'all');

%index = find([shapedata.Area]== max([shapedata.Area]));
index = 213;

data  = shapedata(index).PixelList;

figure
imshow(im)
hold on
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'ro');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try this solution when i find the time to work on this.. i'll let you know..

Comment: I changed my example picture and my approach, so I would appreciate if you could take one more look at the problem.